# grep for single back slash

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to grep for the `mount` output to see the options for the root directory.

Why the following pattern (whitespace before and after a slash) is not working (with and without extended `grep`)

```
/home/pkaramol
$ mount | grep  '/s\//s' 
/home/pkaramol
$ mount | grep -e '/s\//s' 
/home/pkaramol
```

Comment: You are confusing forward slashes with backslashes (`'\s/\s'`) - and also lower case `-e` with upper case `-E`

Comment: nice thanks; if you post this I will accept your answer;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing forward slash `/s` with backslash `\s` - and also lower case `-e` with upper case `-E`:

```
$ mount | grep -E '\s/\s'
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Note that `\s` is really neither a basic regular exression (BRE) nor extended regular expression (ERE) specifier - it really belongs to PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expression) - however at least GNU grep appears to support it in other modes.

Comment: what is the BRE or ERE compliant way for greping for whitespaces?

Comment: @pkaramol `[ \t]` or or `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` (the latter are equivalent except in a multiline context)

Comment: @steeldriver Depending on the libraries used, `[ \t]` might match backslash and `t` and space rather than a tab and space.

Answer (score 2):

To grep the output of `mount` for a single lone slash with GNU `grep`:

```
mount | grep -w '/'
```

With BSD `grep`, just use

```
mount | grep ' / '
```

There is no need for anything more fancy since the `mount` command would output the mount point with simple spaces around it.